# How to use Bison (Yacc) to produce 64bit parser in C++?

Tags: c++, parsing, 64-bit, yacc, bison

Can anyone shed some light on this? From Bison's documentation, I didn't see anything related to this topic. Thanks very much in advance.
Mark

Comment: Whats the difference? C can compile to either 32 bit or 64 bit. Theres no reason to think you need an extra flag...

Comment: D you mean that you want to parse a 64 bit input stream (ie wchar_t is 64 bits per char (aka UTF-32/UCS-4)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bison and Yacc produce a C/C++ code, it depends on your compiler settings what assembly (32/64bit) will be produced.

Comment: Some things are legal in 32bit and wrong in 64bit, eg: int x = someptr - someconstant;

Comment: `int x = someptr - someconstant` is illegal in 32bit code as well. You must always use ptrdiff_t type for pointer differences to avoid undefined behavior.